# Trust wallet ETH auto withdraw?

Tags: ether

I am wondering if it’s possible to automatically withdraw eth from my trust wallet to my main wallet. I run a business and this would make things much easier for me. Basically if I receive eth from a customer it would then IMMEDIATELY transfer it to my main wallet. Is there a program that can do this ? Thanks !

Comment: do contact me on zem.xpert@gmail.com I have the script ready for this sort of job. thanks

Comment: Could you find a solution for this?